# Like WPF GridSplitter open to specific point and then closed on button click

Tags: wpf, animation, gridsplitter

What do i have?
 - Have a wpf usercontrol filling a window with 3 parts left Grid,
   GridSplitter, right Grid.  Right Grid at start is "collasped" (width
   0).

What would i like?
 - On click of a button in the left Grid i'd like the Right Grid to have
   width 200 and the Gridsplitter open it, in a 1 - 1.5 second animation (gracefully :-)
   if you will. On additional click of the left grid button the gridsplitter then closes the right grid
   (also with an animation)...

**Any Ideas that will do it?**

I am not using an expander as the gridsplitter was allows the user to open the right grid herself gradually/partially even.

Right now i am deviding the main grid in the usercontrol up as follows.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use a grid splitter but a button in col 1 (3 column in grid) that spanned the 3 rows (width 15, col width auto) and expander in the col 2 (3rd column width auto) that expanded and closed on clicking the button.

This achieved the result